# Using range in grep

Tags: sed, awk, grep

The following command does work as expected.

```
grep -B3 'Max_value: 127' proc_*.*
```

But I need to compare the number of Max Value and find if it is between 127 and 200.

```
grep -B3 'Max_value: (>127 and <200)' proc_*.*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep 'Max_value:' proc_*.* | awk ' $2 ~ /[0-9]{3}$/ && $2 > 127 && $2 < 200 '
```

edit: adding check for (3 digit numeric)$.

Comment: Very interesting. # but I am getting values like 1984-10-17 and 17:46:07 # Is it possible to check if the $2 value is numeric?

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -B3 -E '^Max_value: (12[789]|1[3-9][0-9]|200)$' proc_*.*
```

The `-E` uses an extended mode that allows alternation without escaping. Otherwise:

```
grep -B3 '^Max_value: \(12[89]\|1[3-9][0-9]\)$' proc_*.*
```

Comment: Nice, but `(>127 and <200)` is required, not `(>=127 and <=200)`

Comment: @Johnsyweb, I assumed because `127` was specified as a _good_ input first of all, that @shantanuo's use of _between_ was _inclusive_, regardless of what his code actually said. :) Good catch. @shantanuo, if you really want _inclusive_ ranges, look in my edit history. :)

Comment: Is it fair to suggest that the regex will allow 'Max_value: 1776' through since the 177 part falls in range?  That mainly makes it messy, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Use awk for your task. The reason being, its easier to compare numbers than manually inputting character classes. What if you need to check a whole wider range.?

```
$ cat file
0
1
2
3
Max_value: 127
a
b
c
d
Max_value: 130
blah1
blah2
blah3
blah4
Max_value: 200
Z
Y
W
X
Max_value: 2001

$ awk -F":" '{a[NR%3]=$0} /Max_value/&&$2>=127&&$2<=200 {for(i=NR+1;i<=NR+3;i++)print a[i%3] }' file
2
3
Max_value: 127
c
d
Max_value: 130
blah3
blah4
Max_value: 200
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you're better of with `awk` in this scenario, but since you asked for a grep solution:

```
$ cat values.txt 
Max_value: 123
Max_value: 600
Max_value: 126
Max_value: 128
Max_value: 130
Max_value: 111
Max_value: 199
Max_value: 200
Max_value: 155
Max_value: 250
$ grep -E "Max_value: (12[89]|1[3-9][0-9])" values.txt 
Max_value: 128
Max_value: 130
Max_value: 199
Max_value: 155
```