# For each line in several files, extract lines containing "XXXX ms" where XXXX is a number > to a given value

Tags: regex, linux, string, console, grep

I have a huge amount of log files and i would like to find every line in all of these logs files where there is the following thing : "XXXX ms" where XXXX represents an integer that is greater than a value of my choice.

How could i use grep (or any other command) to do this ?

I'm using Cygwin (linux console emulator) on Windows.

Example :

```
2013-09-03 11:33:17    11278 ms ProcessMsgDisconnectV2_01 - Disconnection request received from MU.
```

Comment: `where XXXX represents an integer that is greater than a value of my choice.` can you show some example input? usually this kind of job is not for regex.(grep).

Comment: Added an example ! If i choose 10000, this line must be selected, if i choose 20000, it must not.

Comment: Related question with answer using awk: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578302/using-range-in-grep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this line:

```
awk '$4=="ms"&&$3>100' file
```

here the `100` is your value, you can make it better, e.g. get the argument from shell variable, in this way:

```
awk -v va="$value" '$4=="ms"&&$3>va' file
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll go for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a small PHP script: 
Set your minimum value:

```
$minValue = 500;
```

Now loop over all lines. Inside the loop:

```
$line = "test 1456ms"; // your line, here just example
    if (preg_match('/(\d{4})ms/m', $line, $matches)) {
        if ($matches[1][0] > $minValue) echo $line;
    }
}
```

This will check only the first occurrence of XXXXms. 
If you want to check other occurrences, use `preg_match_all` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `perl` one-liner with two arguments, the first one the value to compare and the second the file to search.

```
perl -ne '
    BEGIN { $value = shift } 
    print if m/\b(\d+)\s+ms\b/ && $1 > $value
' 6578 infile
```

Comment: Just to throw out slightly different approach: `perl -lane 'BEGIN {$value=shift} print if $F[3] eq 'ms' && $F[2] > $value' 6578 infile`

Comment: @JoshG79: Yes. And probably easier to adapt with a log file change of layout.